# I need to add spaces between navbar-list items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have difficulty in CSS. The icons are fetched from icons.getbootstrap.com. I need three icons at  the center of the navbar with healthy spaces between them.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">DrugsDirect</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <h1><a href="signup.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <h1><a href="cart.php" class="site-cart"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.5 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-5 0V4h5v-.5zm1 0V4H15v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h3.5v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0zm-.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L7.5 10.793 6.354 9.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <h1><a href="logout.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h8a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 2h8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 3.5v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.146 8.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L1.707 7.5H10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H1.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrDOy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `ms-3` for `margin-start` (`margin-left`) on your second and third list items. You can range from `ms-1` (`.25rem`) to `ms-5` (`3rem`).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">DrugsDirect</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <h1><a href="signup.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ms-3">
          <h1><a href="cart.php" class="site-cart"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.5 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-5 0V4h5v-.5zm1 0V4H15v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h3.5v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0zm-.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L7.5 10.793 6.354 9.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        <li class="nav-item ms-3">
        <h1><a href="logout.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h8a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 2h8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 3.5v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.146 8.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L1.707 7.5H10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H1.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox & column gap as follows :

```html
<ul class="custom-navbar navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
        <h1><a href="signup.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path d="M3 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H3zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <h1><a href="cart.php" class="site-cart"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag-check-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.5 3.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 0-5 0V4h5v-.5zm1 0V4H15v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V4h3.5v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0zm-.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L7.5 10.793 6.354 9.646a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l1.5 1.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        <li class="nav-item">
        <h1><a href="logout.php"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 12.5a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h8a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 6.5 2h8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 16 3.5v9a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 5 12.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2z"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M.146 8.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l3-3a.5.5 0 1 1 .708.708L1.707 7.5H10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H1.707l2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-3-3z"/>
</svg></a></h1>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

```css
.custom-navbar{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:flex-start;
   align-items:center;
   column-gap:1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap solutions shouldn't be solved with additional CSS.